# Select 2 rows from table 1(with UNION) if pair doesn't exist in table 2

Tags: mysql

So i have two tables:

Table  **uno**:

```
id      |  gender  |   lf 
-------------------------
abc   |       1      |    2
cde   |       2      |    1
efg   |       1      |    2
```

table **duo**:

```
id1    |    id2 
-------------------------
abc   |   cde
```

My working (so far) query selects exactly 2 rows from table **uno**:

```
(SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  uno 
WHERE gender = 1 
  AND lf = 2 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1) 
UNION
(SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  uno 
WHERE gender = 2 
  AND lf = 1 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1)
```

Which returns:

```
id    |   gender     | lf
-------------------------
abc   |       1      |    2
cde   |       2      |    1
```

What I need (and haven't figured out if is doable with a query) is to return 2 ids which are not paired in table **duo**.

In this example, the above query shouldn't return `abc` and `cde` because they are already in table duo (possible pairs are efg and abc, efg and cde since they are not found in table duo).

Thanks!

UPDATE:
With the help of chiliNUT i came with this:

```
(SELECT 
  id,gender,lf 
FROM
  uno u1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  /* id1-centric exclusion rule  */
  /* look at id1 FROM duo, exclude it IF it IS IN uno AND id2 IS also IN uno */
  (SELECT 
    d.id1,
    d.id2,
    u2.id 
  FROM
    duo d 
    LEFT JOIN uno u2 /* note the JOIN order, duo on uno */
      ON d.id2 = u2.id 
  WHERE d.id1 = u1.id) 
  /* id2-centric exclusion rule  */
  /* look at id1 FROM duo, exclude it IF it IS IN uno AND id2 IS also IN uno */
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 
    d.id1,
    d.id2,
    u2.id 
  FROM
    uno u2 
    LEFT JOIN duo d /* note the JOIN order, uno on duo */
      ON d.id1 = u2.id 
  WHERE d.id2 = u1.id) and  (gender=1 and lf=2)order by rand() limit 1)UNION(SELECT 
  id,gender,lf 
FROM
  uno u1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  /* id1-centric exclusion rule  */
  /* look at id1 FROM duo, exclude it IF it IS IN uno AND id2 IS also IN uno */
  (SELECT 
    d.id1,
    d.id2,
    u2.id 
  FROM
    duo d 
    LEFT JOIN uno u2 /* note the JOIN order, duo on uno */
      ON d.id2 = u2.id 
  WHERE d.id1 = u1.id) 
  /* id2-centric exclusion rule  */
  /* look at id1 FROM duo, exclude it IF it IS IN uno AND id2 IS also IN uno */
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 
    d.id1,
    d.id2,
    u2.id 
  FROM
    uno u2 
    LEFT JOIN duo d /* note the JOIN order, uno on duo */
      ON d.id1 = u2.id 
  WHERE d.id2 = u1.id) and  (gender=2 and lf=1) order by rand() limit 1)
```

I had to edited so it will come up with 2 ids(with different gender and lf). This for sure is not optimized and will probably hang my DB but its a start!
Thanks chiliNUT!

Comment: @chiliNUT: Please Re-edit query part to occupy few lines but not 1 word per line.

Comment: @RavinderReddy I am using the default auto-format settings from my sql gui (sqlyog)

Comment: @RavinderReddy if you know of a "better" or more "standard" set of formatting rules, please share them! I would be happy to adjust the edit. Since I don't know what formatting convention you are referring to, I can't make the edit. Also, please feel free to make the edit yourself if you know how it could be better formatted.

Comment: @chiliNUT: Good God. OP used a `*`. Else formatting might need a scroll bar for navigating down/up. :)

Comment: I don't think formatting is not just a mater of *better* or *standard* but mostly for readability.

Comment: I know what you mean, I even thought it looked a bit tall when I made the edit, but in general I don't try to second-guess the autoformat function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will select all `id`s in `uno`, wherein the `id` is not a member of an `id1,id2` pair. It looks at each `id` in `uno`, then checks if it matches a `duo.id1`, and if so, it checks if the associated `duo.id2` is also in `uno`. Then, in the other direction, it checks if that `id` in `uno` matches a `duo.id2`, and then checks if the `duo.id1` is also in uno.

```
SELECT 
  id 
FROM
  uno u1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  /* id1-centric exclusion rule  */
  /* look at id1 FROM duo, exclude it if it is in uno AND id2 is also in uno */
  (SELECT 
    d.id1,
    d.id2,
    u2.id 
  FROM
    duo d 
    LEFT JOIN uno u2 /* note the JOIN order, duo on uno */
      ON d.id2 = u2.id 
  WHERE d.id1 = u1.id) 
  /* id2-centric exclusion rule  */
  /* look at id2 FROM duo, exclude it id it is in uno AND id1 is also in uno */
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 
    d.id1,
    d.id2,
    u2.id 
  FROM
    uno u2 
    LEFT JOIN duo d /* note the JOIN order, uno on duo */
      ON d.id1 = u2.id 
  WHERE d.id2 = u1.id)

|id |
+---+
|efg|
```

If you remove the 2nd existance clause, it returns `cde`, but not `abc`. if you remove the 1st existence clause, it returns `abc`, but not `cde`. So both are needed.

Comment: hm, a long one, need to test it and get back 2u. thanks

Comment: yeah, pair (or generally, tuple) checking queries can get big. Haha there might be a more compact solution, but this is what I came up with :-)

Comment: @Theodoros80 you're welcome! Even though the query is a bit large, with good indexing, it may not be terribly inefficient.